# MFMAILCOMPOSER uses uidatepicker or label

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently trying to make an appointment scheduler on an iPad, and I'm at a point where I'm very confused on what to do. I'm at the point where a user needs to input the date of the next appointment which i did with the uidatepicker however it is connected to a uiswitch. now if the switch is turned on the date is then added to an email and sent, however if the uiswitch is off the email should have no date and should be replaced with text that says "no next appointment". I have done a lot of research and was thinking of using a simple if else function however whenever i do use it the app will just crash.

MAILCOMPOSER

```
- (IBAction)sendtoStudentathome:(id)sender {
MFMailComposeViewController *mailContoller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
[mailContoller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
NSString *email = @"admin@hello.com";
NSArray *emailArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:email, nil];


NSString *message = [@[_one.text,_NameofResident.text,_blank.text, _two.text, _NameofStudent.text, _blank1.text, _three.text, _AppointmentTime.date,_blank2.text, _four.text,_NextAppointmentTime.date]componentsJoinedByString: @"\n"];

[mailContoller setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
[mailContoller setToRecipients:emailArray];
[mailContoller setSubject:@"Feedback"];
[self presentViewController:mailContoller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The uidatepicker is the one labeled as "Nextappointmenttime"